# 14.04 - gnome forgets disabled keyboard shortcuts after boot. Is there a workaround?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-control-center

It is a very annoying [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/964270):
I need the keys combination `<ctrl><alt>Arrows` for some other use (eclipse).
But this combination is reserved by gnome for navigation.

Disabling it in Settings>keyboard>shortcuts (gnome-control-center) works fine until I restart Ubuntu.
So I need to disable it again and again every boot.

Is there a command line to disable this combination, and I'll make it run automatically after boot?

Comment: @hakermania - sorry, that link doesn't help.. It is a workaround for another problem the same bug is causing. I need a workaround to disable keyboard shortcuts - and there it's a workaround to set volume using other keyboard shortcut method. (please remove the "possible dup", it may prevent other users from helping out)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Compiz Config Setting Manager (`ccsm`):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it, Go to Preferences → Profile & Backend tab

Because it's a bug, this is just a work around that may work:

- Uncheck *Enable integration into the desktop environment*
- If didn't work, Change Backend to: *Flat-File Configuration Backend*
- If didn't work, Remove write permission from Current profile (`Default` in my case):

  ```
  sudo chmod -w ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/Default.ini
  ```

[image: Compiz backend]

Comment: I'll try this when it happens again, and accept if it works - thanks!